# Full Screen Flash is choppy (nVidia GeForce 8200M)

Tags: video, performance, fullscreen, nvidia-geforce

I have a new compaq presario laptop (I [asked SU for advice](https://superuser.com/questions/29762/considering-the-compaq-presario-laptop-with-amd-athlon-x2-dual-core-processor) before I bought it :-) ).  It has a nVidia GeForce 8200M video card.  When I try to play a flash video full screen, it plays really choppy.  This is a brand new computer and is well more powerful than my previous computer so I know it's not a matter of the full screen being too processor intensive to play, or a bandwidth problem.  Even playing HD hulu videos full screen was fine on my previous laptop.

Any advice on how to get better performance here?

*edit:* World Of Warcraft is able to play at a great framerate, so this machine should definitely be able to handle a simple little flash video ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and video card. Then someone recommended to turn off ''enable hardware acceleration'' by right clicking the video and clicking settings. Now my flash videos play normally on full screen. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Flash video seems to be choppy no matter what type of video card you have - at least it's never been very tolerable for me. The [Lifehacker article on adjusting the Firefox session save time](http://lifehacker.com/5342636/how-to-fix-annoying-youtube-jumpiness-in-firefox) does seem to help.

[image]

http://xkcd.com/619/

Answer (score 1):

It is usually a drivers problem.. Hope you have the latest drivers.
Here is [a link for the Compaq Presario CQ60-418DX Notebook PC](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?sw_lang=8&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&product=3989789) you refer in the other question.

---

With updated drivers, check your memory and processor utilization.

- Is your system memory nearly used up?
- Do you have the latest DirectX? ...

Here is a nVidia forum thread on the same topic!
[Trying to play WoW with GeForce 8200M G](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?s=88576d81e4c58625b88ec1a0f9761569&showtopic=85306&mode=linearplus)

Comment: Thank you for the link, but yes I do have the latest driver installed.  I verified in device manager that I had v7.15.11.7614

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=ob-64449-1&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&os=2093&product=3989789&sw_lang=8&lang=en

Comment: well, WoW actually plays splendidly on this laptop ... great framerate.  So it shouldn't be that.

Comment: Well, WoW is not really demanding graphically nowadays. It runs on a Geforce 4 without a problem, typically. But anyway, keep in mind that flash is not optimized for graphical cards as a game would be, there is no link.

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem with the latest version of flash that makes it lagy at times, but also if you are using firefox, it could be with that -

[Here is a post I made before](https://superuser.com/questions/29790/why-are-all-flash-videos-lagging-a-lot)

---

Recently there was a article about Firefox slowing down on videos due to the internal process that saves all open tabs every 10 seconds - you can increase this by going to about:config and increasing the timeout on browser.sessionstore.interval

[Article](http://lifehacker.com/5342636/how-to-fix-annoying-youtube-jumpiness-in-firefox)

Personally, I have a good graphics card and fast CPU and see random problems, slow downs and lag in various flash videos. I think the latest few releases are buggy and need refining as I never had this problem in a older version on a slower machine.

I hope the first solution helps you as I know it has helped a lot of people - just not me!

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-8200M-G.11360.0.html) says about the NVIDIA GeForce 8200M G : "the performance of the chip is hardly sufficient for very modest games with low details". It might be that you'll have to live with this problem and wait for driver updates. You might also check for BIOS updates.

There are also external graphics cards now for laptops:
[AMILO Graphic Booster](http://www.trustedreviews.com/laptops/news/2008/11/26/Fujitsu-Launches-Amilo-Graphics-Booster/p1)
[ATI XGP](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/ati-xgp/Pages/ati-xgp.aspx)

Comment: I can play world of warcraft full screen with no problems.

Comment: WoW is not very demanding, graphically. Check if the BIOS is up to date (but take care when updating). If everything checks out but the performance is still weak for some operations, then there's nothing more that you can do. Except for waiting for newer drivers (that may never arrive). You might be obliged to reduce the display area for some graphical operations on this laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Which resolution do you use ?

Because typically, I have a 7950 GTX on my laptop, it's not recent, but still a good graphical card. I'm in 1920x1200 on desktop, and I have slower flash in fullscreen (unpleasant to watch videos).

Keep in mind that fullscreen flash is hardly optimized, it's mostly a "stretching". So if you use a big resolution, the fullscreen has better chances to be slow.

Comment: My resolution is set to 1366 x 768