# Flash crashing Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, flash, crash

In his recent blogpost, [Thoughts on Flash](http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/), Steve Jobs says:

> We also know first hand that Flash is
>   the number one reason Macs crash.

My best guess is that Flash runs in user-mode, with restricted privileges. Is is impossible to crash a system having restricted privileges.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

He wasn't talking about kernel panics (full OS crashes), he was talking about app crashes. He should have phrased it a little differently.  His meaning would've been more clear if he had said "Flash is the number one cause of crashes on the Mac".

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult, but not impossible. Just because you can't access memory in kernel space directly doesn't mean you can't call a library function that does it for you.

Comment: Then this problem would be related to a bad implementation on kernel code, not any userspace app.

Answer (score 0):

He meant the browser. You can use flashblock stuff for Safari, use Chrome with its own flash/isolation support and Firefox with flashblock. (Like this you can avoid most of the crashes). (Later you may be able to use [Firefox Lorentz](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/lorentz/). (Now its avaliable for Windows and Linux).

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is true.

Macs are not powered by regular components, they use special magical components that never fail under any circumstance.

....

Software wise (as Spiff said) I can just about believe this as a few years ago as various flash websites would crash my browser (IE and Firefox), however, I have not had a flash crash in some years now - instead it just hogs my CPU at full! ([link 1](https://superuser.com/questions/35437/how-to-fix-the-firefox-using-max-cpu-problem/35445#35445), [link 2](https://superuser.com/questions/43551/how-to-stop-flash-from-raising-my-cpu-temperature/43553#43553), [link 3](https://superuser.com/questions/29790/why-are-all-flash-videos-lagging-a-lot/29795#29795).)

Hardware wise, I see a rather large percentage of Macs (in relation to other brands) in for repair - usually down to hard drive related problems. They do crash, and they crash often.

Comment: I'm sorry you've had bad luck with hard drives in your Macs, but since Apple uses the same makes and models of third-party hard drives as any other PC vendor, and since Consumer Reports regularly ranks Apple as having some of the most reliably hardware, I think your anecdote is non-representative.

Comment: @Spiff - I don't use Macs, I run a computer service company and I see a large percentage of repairs being Macs (And I am a member of many panels that provide information to reports)... I was just saying that Macs have just as many problems as other machines and do not have magical parts that never fail.

Comment: If you don't run a Mac, you can't say that Flash doesn't crash one just because you run Flash without a crash. It is a very poorly ported piece of software and is much less stable on the Mac. The authoring environment is similarly less stable and slower too.